# Error in Chrome 67+, the permission window is never displayed

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I have a issue for chrome 67+ the permission window is never displayed, according to the documentation ([push-notification](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user)) the parameter applicationServerKey is mandatory form chrome, Is it possible to add this parameter? I think that this parameter should be added inside the backend to support it.

The Line in the SDK Library:

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-javascript-webpush/blob/master/BMSPushSDK.js#L366

Answer (score 0):

From Chrome 68 (beta) the applicationServerKey is mandatory for subscribing push notifications. On the next release of IBM Cloud Web-push SDK we will add applicationServerKey option.
 Kindly follow this - [issue: 403534206](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-push-notifications/Web_HelloPush/issues/6#issuecomment-403534206)